# Is there an easy way to insert data/time in front of a log file with just shell scripting?

Tags: scripting, unix-shell, top, pipe, timestamp

Say I want to monitor memory usage on a java process overnight.

I can do something like

top | grep java > out.log

I will get a log file with a whole bunch of lines.

Is there an easy way to get a data/time inserted in front of each line?

Answer (score 3):

Don't reinvent the wheel. Write the messages to syslog using [logger(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/logger), which is supported on just about every Unix flavor. Syslog will take care of the timestamps for you. Your log data will be stored to a system log like `/var/log/messages` (This is configurable). You don't need to worry about cleaning up the logfiles later on (especially if this job runs forever), because the system logs are automatically rotated by logrotate/newsyslog.

```
top | grep java | logger -t java_cpuhog
```

Or, if you really want to write it to your own file. But then you need to clean up the file afterwards:

```
top | grep java | logger -t java_cpuhog -f /var/log/java-top.log
```

Comment: This. logger must be one of the most under-valued pieces of software there are. Some wrapper should yell "USE logger instead, YOU FOOL!" at you every time it detects pattern like `date >>/var/log/myapp.log && echo "I'm just logging here." >>/var/log/myapp.log`

Comment: I think you need to be root for this (which I am not :-( )

Comment: @James : No, regular users can use `logger` to write to the system logs. Remember about all those other unix programs which run as other users-- they still log to syslog. Many of them don't run as root.

Comment: @James : Although, you might need to be root to read from some of the system logs. However I believe that, `/var/log/messages` should be readable by most users on a system. To test this, do `echo jamestest | logger`, and then look or the output in `/var/log/messages`.

Comment: Also note that you can still use the second option above. `echo stefantest | logger -f ~/stefantest.log`

Answer (score 2):

```
... | awk -f timetag.awk > ...
```

timetag.awk:

```
{
  print "[" strftime() "] " $0
}
```

Comment: For versions of AWK that don't have `strftime`: `... | awk '{"date" | getline d; close("date"); print "[" d "] " $0}'` which also illustrates doing it as a one-liner (it could be put in a script file as in the answer above).

Comment: Your one liner works fine on Linux. On Solaris it gives me this error:awk '{"date" | getline d; close("date"); print "[" d "] " $0}'
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: illegal statement near line 1

Answer (score 1):

In shell:   `top | grep java | while read LINE ; do date "+%F %T ${LINE}" ; done`

Comment: `%D` and `%F` are redundant. Perhaps you meant `%F` and `%T`?

Answer (score 0):

You could create something like `stamp` containing

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -p
s/^/localtime()." "/e;
```

Then run

```
top -b | grep java | stamp > out.log
```

Don't forget to use `top -b` if you are not using it interactively.  Of course, top already puts a timestamp each time it runs.  If you don't necessarily need the date on each line, just use top on its own since it puts a timestamp on each iteration.  I sometimes use this to get 10 second samples for a full day to review later:

```
top -b -d 10 -c -n 8640
```

Comment: Better Perl would be to not even have a regex.  `$_ = localtime() . ' ' . $_`.